# How do I get key values from calling method

Tags: java, encryption

So in my method simpleTests in class TestCaesarCipherTwo I call another method, breakCaeserTwo to perform the decryption of an encrypted message. I would also like to have this same breakCaesarTwo method used to figure out the keys used in decryption. Right now my code looks like this:

```
 public void simpleTests()
    {
        int key1 = 17;
        int key2 = 3;
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String message = fr.asString();
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(key1, key2);
        String encrypted = cctk.encrypt(message);
        System.out.println(encrypted);

        String decrypted = cctk.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);

        BreakCaesarThree bct = new BreakCaesarThree();
        String broken = breakCaesarTwo(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);    
  }
```

I have `Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken` using an instance of BreakCaesarThree(bct) to get the keys. My encryption and decryption code only seems to work when I'm calling the method breakCaesarTwo into simpleTests. So my question now is how does one call a method and use it to get the encryption keys, like when I found the keys with BreakCaesarThree using ".bct"?

Note: I do not want to use BreakCaesarThree or any instance of it in my code. I want to refer directly to the breakCaesarTwo method already in the code. I want to know if there is a way to call this method and get key values, like I have done with BreakCaesarThree, using ".bct". What would be the syntax for such a change?
  Here's the code for the method breakCaesarTwo:

```
public String breakCaesarTwo(String input) {
    String in_0 = halfOfString(input, 0);
    String in_1 = halfOfString(input, 1);
    // Find first key
    // Determine character frequencies in ciphertext
    int[] freqs_0 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_0);
    // Get the most common character
    int freqDex_0 = maxIndex(freqs_0);
    // Calculate key such that 'E' would be mapped to the most common ciphertext character
    // since 'E' is expected to be the most common plaintext character
    int dkey_0 = freqDex_0 - 4;
    // Make sure our key is non-negative
    if (dkey_0 < 0) {
        dkey_0 = dkey_0+26;
    }
    // Find second key
    int[] freqs_1 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_1);
    int freqDex_1 = maxIndex(freqs_1);
    int dkey_1 = freqDex_1 - 4;
    if (freqDex_1 < 4) {
        dkey_1 = dkey_1+26;
    }
    CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey_0, dkey_1);
    return cctk.decrypt(input);
  }
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Why don't you edit the breakCaeserTwo method so it returns the broken string *and* the keys? (You'll need to make a small class holding both, and return an instance of this class, since Java methods can only have one return value)

Comment: I've added the breakCaesarTwo method in the code above. How would I change breakCaesarTwo to reflect what  you just said exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper class such as:

```
public class DecryptionResult {
    String decryptedValue;
    String key1;
    String key2;

    public DecryptionValue(String decryptedValue, String key1, String key2) {
        this.decryptedValue = decryptedValue;
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public String getDecryptedValue() {
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }
}
```

... and make your `breakCaesarTwo` method return an instance of `DecryptionResult`:

```
public DecryptionResult breakCaesarTwo(String input) {
    ...
    CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey_0, dkey_1);
    return new DecryptedResult(cctk.decrypt(input), dkey_0, dkey_1);
}
```

Comment: What should go in the place of getters?

Comment: Edited to include getters.